# How to use Active Directory groups with workflows?

Tags: workflow, active-directory, groups

Is there a way to use Active Directory  groups with Workflows 2013?

From what I have experimented the workflow starts but then gives operation cancelled.
I have read that someone saying that it's not possible and I should give permission to each AD user. But this is not a viable option as I have too many users.

**EDIT:**
Configuration database version: 15.0.4535.1000

**EDIT 2:**
I have updated to:
Configuration database version: 15.0.4569.1000
the problems remains.

**EDIT 3:**
I stepped down to Workflow 2010 as with that version it works

Comment: Yes you can. What version of SharePoint and SP/CU are you using?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: You can simply grant permissions to AD group. But how is this related to your workflows?

Comment: Which Service Pack and which Cumulative Update? Can you list the version in the Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Servers in Farm

Comment: check this one may be related...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b568b4ab-52b4-40c5-887b-56a5ebd9144d/sharepoint-2013-workflow-spd-2013-fails-for-active-directory-group-members?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Waqas Sarwar MCSE It didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Mike I edited with the info you were asking.

Comment: @Mike, you said it was possible. Could you tell me how? I updated my SP environoment (see edit 2)

Answer (score 5):

You have to include the AD Groups in the user profile sync connection. If your AD Groups are not sync'd with the UPS, then it won't be possible. Make sure the UPS Sync connection includes the containers that the AD Groups are in.